# extract/filter syslog-ng log on linux

Tags: syslog-ng

I have configured syslog-ng to receive log from another machine, the logs are coming every minute but contains , how to filter unrequired messages from row data ?

Example:
`date=2021-06-01 time=10:01:01 ABC="1" cde=2 Xyz="aaa" name=UK`
`date=2021-06-01 time=10:01:02 ABC="3" cde=5 name=USA`
`date=2021-06-01 time=10:01:03 ABC="4" cde=2`

output of syslog-ng needs to be as below :

2020-06-01/data-20200601.log:

```
`date=2021-06-01 time=10:01:01 ABC="1" cde=2 Xyz="aaa" name=UK `
```

`date=2021-06-01 time=10:01:02 ABC="3" cde=5 XyZ="" name=USA`

`date=2021-06-01 time=10:01:03 ABC="4" cde=2 XyZ="" name=""`

mean filter based on KEY= and if value missing the KEY= should be logged with "" ( so missing value won't be shifted to left ) , so I can filter later as per my need :

I tried to parse with awk & sed but the size of log file generated by syslog "data-20200601.log" is around 10GB and took me long time to get this output

```
2021-06-01,10:01:01,1,2,aaa,UK  

2021-06-01,10:01:02,3,5,,USA   

2021-06-01,10:01:03,4,,,,
```

Answer (score 0):

syslog-ng has a parser called kv-parser() that would extract all such key=value parts into syslog-ng name-value pairs.

```
log {
    source(some_source);
    parser { kv-parser(); };
    destination { file("this_is_where_all_logs_go" template("${name} ${ABC}")); };
};
```

In the template section, as you can see, you can reference the extracted name-value pairs, using the normal syslog-ng syntax.

You can even format a series of name-value pairs into JSON or other structured formats using $(format-json), $(format-welf), etc.